# C Newbie/ not understanding what might the problem be

Tags: c

since im learning C language i decided to make a simple program that adds, substracts and calculates the product of two variables . Depending on users' input whether its 1,2 or 3 to choose addition/substraction/folding.

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void) {
   int a, b, c, d, e, f, g;
   a=19;   b=11;  c=a+b;  d=a-b;  e=a*b;  f=-1;

   while (f<0 && f>3) {
      printf("-press 1 to calculate the sum of a and b\n");
      printf("-press 2 to calculate the difference between a and b\n");
      printf("-press 3 to calculate the product of a and b\n");

      scanf("%d\n",&g);
      f=g;
      return;
   }

   if (f == 1) {
      printf("A+B= %ls\n", &c);
   } else if (f == 2) {
      printf("A-B= %ls\n", &d);
   } else if (f == 3) {
      printf(" A*B= %ls\n", &e);
   }
return 0;
}
```

> When i run the program its reads "g" and then it stops.
>   any suggestions to why is this happening
>   btw i also tried removing the **while** statement.

Comment: *"when i run the program its reads "g" and then it stops. any suggestions to why is this happening"* It happens because you have `return;` immediately after that.

Comment: `while (f<0 && f>3)` - find me any value of `f` where *both* of those conditions are true. Pretty sure you mean `||` , not `&&`

Comment: With `printf` of an int, you don't use `&`; you just pass the variable.

Comment: The format specification `%ls` is not correct to print an integer. Use `%d`.

Comment: You can remove the `return;` which will cause the program to always stop running at that point.

Comment: `printf()`is not used with adress operator `&` to show an `int` value. You will print the address of the relative `int` variable with this instead (if it might work in general). An `int` value is also not specified with `%ls`, it is specified with `%i` or `%d`. Also `return;` inside the body of the loop makes no sense, because it will exit the program at the end of the first loop run.

Comment: It looks like you forgot to enable a good set of warnings.  For GCC, I recommend `-Wall -Wextra -Wwrite-strings` as a minimum; consider also `-Wpedantic -Warray-bounds` for identifying some other common mistakes.

Comment: Oh, and *never* ignore the return value of `scanf()` like that!

Comment: yes the i meant "or" not "and" and another problem was the endline in scanf()

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean the following while loop

```
while ( f < 0 || f > 3 )
{
     printf("-press 1 to calculate the sum of a and b\n");
     printf("-press 2 to calculate the difference between a and b\n");
     printf("-press 3 to calculate the product of a and b\n");
     scanf( "%d", &g );
     f = g;
}
```

That is pay attention to 1) the condition of the while loop, 2) removed the return statement and 3) removed the character `'\n'` in scanf because it is redundant.

And in printf calls remove the operator & and use the conversion specifier %d.

```
 if ( f == 1 ) {
  printf(" A+B= %d\n", c) ;
 }
 else if ( f == 2) {
  printf(" A-B= %d\n", d );
 }
 else if ( f == 3 ) {
  printf(" A*B= %d\n",e );
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed you code and added some comments to it. Hope you can understand it! If you have questions, just comment them.

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void) {
   // values can be given to ints by int a = value
   int a = 19, b = 11, c, d, e, f = -1, g;

   // '||' means OR, while '&&' means AND. 
   // A value can't be smaller then and bigger then 3 at the same time
   while (f < 0 || f > 3) {
      printf("-press 1 to calculate the sum of a and b\n");
      printf("-press 2 to calculate the difference between a and b\n");
      printf("-press 3 to calculate the product of a and b\n");

      scanf("%d", &g);   //you don't need \n for scanf
      f=g;
      // return stops the program. In this case, this is not what you want
   }

   // For printf you don't need &e, &f, etc.
   // Instead of calculating a value and storing it in a different int,
   // you can just print the outcome of the calculation.
   if (f == 1) {
      printf("A + B = %d\n", a + b);
   } else if (f == 2) {
      printf("A - B = %d\n", a - b);
   } else if (f == 3) {
      printf(" A * B = %d\n", a * b);
   }
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 while (f<0 && f>3){
  printf("-press 1 to calculate the sum of a and b\n");
  printf("-press 2 to calculate the difference between a and b\n");
  printf("-press 3 to calculate the product of a and b\n");
  scanf("%d\n",&g);
  f=g;
  // remove the "return" from here;
 }
```

Also change :

```
printf(" A+B= %ls\n",&c);
```

To:

```
printf(" A+B= %d\n",c);
```

You don't need the '&' operator to print values, if used it will print the address and not the resultant value.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to add that you could replace your if/else if statements with the switch/case . To be more specific (after changing some small mistakes in your code %d instead %ls and so on) the section of your code should look like this:

```
// code above
switch(f) {
     case 1:
       printf(" A+B= %d\n", c) ; 
       break; // if you want the program to stop after doing this operation
     case 2:
       printf(" A-B= %d\n", d );
       break;
     case 3:
       printf(" A*B= %d\n",e );
       break;
 //  default: // if the input is not one of the above(1,2 or 3) 
 //    printf(" Please give a valid option. \n");
 //    break;
```